# Is there a way to get the original request URL with params in a Filter without Rebuilding

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I have a servlet Filter inside a Java EE project and need to obtain the original request url and the URL params. I am currently rebuilding the original URL with the following code, but this feels completely wrong:

```
StringBuilder urlBuilder = new StringBuilder(req.getScheme()+"://"+req.getServerName()+":"+req.getServerPort()+req.getContextPath());
if(req.getParameterMap() != null && req.getParameterMap().size() > 0) urlBuilder.append("?"+getParameterString(req.getParameterMap()));

private StringBuilder getParameterString(Map<String, String[]> params){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
    for(String key : params.keySet()){
        for(String param : params.get(key)){
            sb.append(String.format("%s=%s&", key, param));
        }
    }
    return sb;
}
```

What I would really like to do is something more like the following:

```
req.getUrlWithParams()
```

This seeems better since I am effectively undoing what the servlet container has done parsing the parameters in and all I actually want to do is to receive the original URL unparsed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your request object is an instance of [HttpServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html), you can do this.

```
if (req instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
    HttpServletRequest httpReq = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    StringBuffer url = httpReq.getRequestURL();
    if (httpReq.getQueryString() != null) {
        url.append("?");
        url.append(httpReq.getQueryString());
    }
    String urlString = url.toString();
}
```

Comment: Incorrect result if `getQueryString()` returns `null`. Also, javadoc of [`getRequestURL()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL()) says: *Because this method returns a `StringBuffer`, not a string, you can modify the URL easily, for example, to **append query parameters**.* So why not do that?

Comment: Thanks @Andreas, I've updated my answer to do a null check for `getQueryString()` and used `StringBuffer` to populate the rest of the URL.

Comment: No you haven't. This code does not even compile. `getRequestURL()` doesn't return a `String`, as @Andreas has already noted, and even if it did the subsequent `append()` calls do nothing to the strings they are called on.

Comment: My bad @EJP... I was sure I changed `String url` to `StringBuffer url` but I should have double checked. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: The original answer was good enough to get a rough idea of where to look in the APIs, but thank you for updating it for those Googling.